Any limitations on creating an OAuth Connected App in Salesforce Essentials edition?
Are there any limitations to creating an OAuth connected app in Salesforce Essentials edition vs the higher editions like Professional, Enterprise, etc.? Are there any restrictions that I should be aware of?
Eg: Number of API calls that can go through the app, if all types of accounts (Dev, Sandbox, Prod) are not supported or maybe a limitation on number of users who can authenticate using one app, etc.

Have you tried doing a search before asking? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385436&type=1
